# Split SQL rows array into multiple arrays based on date

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I was surprised not to find this already answered (that I could see anyway) but I'm looking to pull a series of rows from an SQL database into an array using PHP and then split that array into multiple arrays based on the date field of each entry (either by matching date or day of the week).

I have no idea how to do this and have attempted instead to just run a while loop for each day of the week (there is both a day and date field in my database, probably unnecessary I realise)

Am I trying to achieve this the right way or is there perhaps a simpler solution?

```
$result = mysqli_query($sql, $query); 

echo '<div class="column">';

while (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) && ($row['day'] == 'Monday'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$days = array('Monday' => array(), 'Tuesday' => array(), ...);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $days[$row['day']][] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that looks like it would solve my problem. Forgive the simple question but how would I then echo a value from one of the new arrays?

Comment: `echo $days[$dayname][$i][$colname]`

Comment: I can't seem to get that working. Each row from the database contain 'id', 'day', 'name'. I tried: echo $days[$Monday][$i][$name] but it came up with an error. What does the variable $i do out of interest?

Comment: Since each `$days[$dayname]` contains an array of rows for that day, `$i` is the index of a particular row.

Comment: I outputed the content of the $days array and this is what I got: [Monday] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => [name] => John [day] => Monday ) )
[Tuesday] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => [name] => David [day] => Tuesday)) 
I didn't add any further days so that isn't a problem. Really appreciate any help you can give!

Comment: So use `$days['Tuesday'][0]['name']`, for example. If there were another Tuesday row, you would use `$days['Tuesday'][1]['name']`, and so on.

Comment: That's worked, thank you so much for your help, it's really appreciated. You've helped me learn something.